# FQL query limits the results to 25

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Hi I am trying to fetch total no of movies i liked but graph API restricts the results to 25. I have tried using the Timestamp until and also LIMIT keyword but still only 25 movies are getting fetched. My code goes like this

```
 query = "https://graph.facebook.com/USER_NAME?limit=200&access_token=%s&fields=name,movies" % TOKEN
    result = requests.get(query)
    data = json.loads(result.text)
    fd = open('Me','a')
    for key in data:
        if key=='movies':
            fd.write("KEY: MOVIES\n")
            #print data[key]
            count = len((data[unicode(key)])['data'])
            fd.write("COUNT = "+str(count)+"\n")
            for i in (data[unicode(key)])['data']:
                fd.write((i['name']).encode('utf8'))
                fd.write("\n")
```

Please help me in fixing it

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

Since the platform update on October the 2nd, there are only 25 likes returned at once via the Graph API (see https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/), and Movies are Likes. You can either implement result pagination, or use the FQL table **page_fan** with the following FQL:

```
select page_id, name from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_fan where uid=me() and profile_section = 'movies')
```

You have to count the entries in your application, FB has no aggregation functionality.